# Laravel: Optional route prefix parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, parameters, routes

I'm currently working on a multi-site application (one codebase for multiple (sub)sites) and I would love to leverage route caching, but currently I'm hardcoding a prefix instead of dynamically determining it.

When trying to do this I'm running into an issue which I've illustrated below:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{subsite}', 'subdomain' => '{site}.domain.tld'], function () {
    Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
});
```

When accessing a subsite like `http://sitename.domain.tld/subsitename/blog` this all works fine, but it doesn't work anymore when not accessing a subsite like `http://sitename.domain.tld/blog`, as it will now think that the prefix is 'blog'.

Is there any way to allow the 'subsite' parameter to be empty or skipped?

Thanks!

Comment: Laravel does have optional parameters but these can only be used as the last parameter in the list, I think your best option is wrapping all your routes which need to have the optional subsite in a function and create 2 route groups, one with the subsite and one without

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there isn't anything in the current routing system that would allow you to solve your problem with a single route group.

While this doesn't answer your specific question, I can think of two ways that you could implement your expected behaviour.

## 1. Duplicate the route group

```
Route::group(['subdomain' => '{site}.domain.tld'], function () {
    Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '{subsite}', 'subdomain' => '{site}.domain.tld'], function () {
    Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
});
```

## 2. Loop through an array of expected prefixes.

```
$prefixes = ['', 'subsiteone', 'subsitetwo'];

foreach($prefixes as $prefix) {
    Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'subdomain' => '{site}.domain.tld'], function () {
        Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jeemusu! The problem with these approaches  is that the named routes would overwrite each other, so going to `route('blog.index')` would always link to the last defined route. And unfortunately the second approach won't work with route caching :(

Comment: Ah, my mistake! The name would need to be changed to be unique for each prefix.